# Bonobo-Git-Server anonymous access to a repository

Tags: bonobo

I have created a repository and checked the Anonymous check box. However when I try to access it the repository link directly with no login, I was redirected to the login page. Anyone can help on this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. After seeing no answers to your question I fired up the source code and started debugging. My conclusion is *this is not supported*.

The action methods are decorated with `WebAuthorize`, a custom attribute that inherits from the usual `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Unfortunately, the base `AuthorizeAttribute` returns an `HttpUnauthorizedResult` for anonymous users and so it doesn't appear to be able to use this software without being logged in. Which regretfully is kind of pointless as I *want* anonymous access and don't want user account registration to be enabled or required.

Short of changing the source code, this doesn't seem to be possible. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Hi Richard. I found that someone can setup as anonymous access on the following link. https://git.denhome.ru/Repository/Tree/55b8f8ea-3d1a-446b-bc74-fba36c43b2a8